# Represent Mysql raw query with Typeorm QueryBuilder

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I want to represent below mysql sql query with typeorm query builder:

```sql
SELECT
  new_rec.*
FROM (SELECT Replace(Replace(Replace(Json_extract(industries, '$[*].id'), '[', ''), ']', ''), ' ', '') AS ids, 
  recruiter.* 
FROM recruiter.recruiter) new_rec 
WHERE Find_in_set('14', new_rec.ids) > 0 AND Find_in_set('16', new_rec.ids) > 0;
```

Could anyone expertise in typeorm help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const subQuery = connection
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .select(`
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            JSON_EXTRACT(recruiter.industries, '$[*].id'),
                            '[',
                            ''
                        ),
                        ']',
                        ''
                    ),
                    ' ',
                    ''
                ) AS ids,
                recruiter.*
            `)
            .from('recruiter', 'recruiter');
        const selectQuery = this.connection
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .select('*')
            .from('(' + subQuery.getQuery() + ')', 'recruiter');
        selectQuery.getRawMany();
```

With this query, you would get the same result as mysql query.

Answer (score 0):

You probably resolved this but to benefit others who want to use the MySQL SET type with typeorm -

Here is the column in a typeORM entity:
We initially used an enum as per typeorm documentation which did work, but wasn't needed for our requirements. We therefore opted to skip the enum and only use string[].

```
@Column({ type: 'set' })

gradeLevels: string[];
```

Using TypeORM repo find:

```
gradeLevels: Raw(col => `FIND_IN_SET('${gradeLevel}', ${col}) > 0`)
```

Using TypeORM queryBuilder:

```
.andWhere('FIND_IN_SET(:gradeLevel, question.gradeLevels) > 0', { gradeLevel })
```